# How to pass by reference (simulation)

Tags: javascript, scope, reference

I'm having a trouble approaching to this problem, althouh I have a working solution I doubt it is the most optimal one.

**Here is the problem:**

*Imagine an array of objects, each object represents a person.*

```
var people = [
{id:1, name:"John", points: 50},
{id:2, name:"Mark", points: 80},
{id:3, name:"Peter", points: 25},
];
```

In our people array, we have 3 persons with an **unique id** property.

Now imagine that we have multiple functions that modify/update person objects.

> Obviously this wouldn't work, since the outer object won't be affected
>   by the changes made in incrementPoints() function.

```
var myPerson = people[0]; 

incrementPoints(myPerson){
  myPerson.points++;
};

// myPerson.points = 50
addPoints(myPerson); // We're passing an person object to addPoints;
// myPerson.points = 50 (Did not change, not affected by addPoints)
```

> This however, would work! But the price we pay is the cost of
>   iteration through persons array and matching the id of desired person.

```
function getPersonIndexById(personId){
 // Iterate through all persons in 'people' array 
 for(var index = 0; index < people.length; index++)
   people[i].id === personId ? return index : continue; 
}

function incrementPoints(personId){
people[ getPersonIndexById(personId) ].points++;
}

function decrementPoints(personId){
people[ getPersonIndexById(personId) ].points--;
}
```

Is there a better/simpler/cleaner/intended concept for dealing with such situations. Obviously, the ideal solution would be a pass by &reference but javascript does not allow that. I'm not trying to do achieve an useless hack, but rather get understanding of what developers do when they stumble upon similar situations and how they solve them.

Comment: `myPerson.points++;` does work... `var people = [{id:1, name:"John", points: 50},{id:2, name:"Mark", points: 80},{id:3, name:"Peter", points: 25}];
var myPerson = people[0]; 

function incrementPoints(myPerson){
  myPerson.points++;
};
incrementPoints(myPerson);
console.log(myPerson);` -> Object {id: 1, name: "John", points: 51}

Comment: ... and it will always work, as objects are always passed as a value of a reference.

Comment: I thought... perhaps incorrectly, that Java passes a value for a reference.  So, in your first example, it would actually work.  You can't change myPerson, but changing myPerson.points is reflected in the original object.  myPerson is the value item, but still references people[0].

Comment: Javascript functions are pass by value, but when it comes to objects and arrays, the value passed in is the reference to the object.  This reference to that outer object cannot be changed inside the function, but it can be used to access and edit its properties, just as you did with `myPerson.points++`

Comment: @juan8a so if inside a function i tried to add a new property and assign it a value like this: `myPerson.age = 20`, would that be treated as an edit (and preserve the reference) or would that clone the original object + add new property?

Comment: yes, it would change the object by adding the property to it.  See this Codepen I just coded up for you:  http://codepen.io/jose8a/pen/YWNxYJ?editors=0011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var people = [
  {id:1, name:"John", points: 50},
  {id:2, name:"Mark", points: 80},
  {id:3, name:"Peter", points: 25},
];

var myPerson = people[0]; 

function incrementPoints(myPerson){
  myPerson.points++;
};

function addPropertyToPerson(myPerson, lastname) {
  myPerson.lastName = lastname;
}

// The properties of the myPerson object can still be modified since 
// the value passed in to the function is the reference to the object
incrementPoints(myPerson);
console.log(myPerson);

// Similarly, additional properties can still be added since 
// the value passed in to the function is the reference to 
// the outer object
addPropertyToPerson(myPerson, "smith"); 
console.log(myPerson);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for clearing this out. Additional question if you don't mind - when will the inner object loose it's reference to the original object, besides from when explicitly assigning another value to myPerson? If that is even possible (to implicitly loose a reference by accessing/editing the inner object)

Comment: If I understand your new question, then the reference to the outer/original object is lost as soon as the function exits, unless a closure is created.  Every time a function is invoked/executed, a new execution context is created for it, and all of the variables, arguments, scope chains, etc are created anew for each new copy.  Even if it is the same function being invoked over and over again, its "machinery", if you will, is recreated each time.  Unless, as I mentioned earlier, it creates a closure. In that case, the closure environment will persist until the closure is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

- Objects are passed as reference
- You defined a function with name `incrementPoints` with a wrong syntax but you are calling `addPoints`. I hope it is a typo/mistake.
- if I suppose it is `addPoints` then it is working fine. You will get 51 points after that function call.
- You can use `Array.prototype.find` to find a person by id, it is builtin and it will be fast.

```html
function incrementPoints(personId){

       var person = people.find(function(p){
            return p.id === personId;
       });
      if (person) {
         person.points++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: That was certainly a typo, it was only important for you to understand the problem which you did. Array.prototype.find was seems great. But since objects are passed as a reference it is pretty much straight forward. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to convert array to map while getting data.

`var personMap = {};  people.forEach(function(person){`
`personMap[id] = person;`
`});`

With this now you have map

You can get person as `personMap[personId]`

Here creating map is one time activity so you need a single round of iteration

Please bear with my response.. I am replying from mobile so formatting might be not good

Comment: Formatting looks great. I just learned that objects are passed as a reference, which means that mapping ids or accessing an object in array by array index is not the optimal solution (for this case) because we can simply pass the object and mutate it which is the most simple and fastest solution.